# How many column switches have occurred?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

If I look at the permutation $[1,2,...,n] \to [2,3,...,n,1]$, how many column switches have occurred?

I'm pretty sure it's n switches, and so the corresponding permutation matrix has determinant =$ (-1)^n.$

The solution gives $ (-1)^{n+1}. $ It's probably a typo, or I may have possibly overlooked something.

Thanks,

Comment: The solution is correct

Comment: Note that there are many sequences of transpositions ("switches") whose product is the given permutation. All that we can ask for is (1) the minimal number of transpositions required and (2) the parity of the number required, as the parity is the same for all sequences that give this permutation---the parity is what we call the *sign* of the permutation.

Comment: Thanks so much @travis :-)

Comment: @LebronJames You're welcome, I hope you found it useful.

Comment: Doesn't considering $n=2$ settle it pretty quickly, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(a,b)$ denote the switch of $a$ and $b$. Note that you can permute $n$ elements with the following sequence of switches (in order from left to right):
$$
(1,2),(2,3),\dots,(n-1,n)
$$
In total, that's $n-1$ switches. The solution is then $(-1)^{n-1} = (-1)^{n+1}$, so the given solution is correct.

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, so, 2 goes to 1, 3 goes to 2, ... , n goes to (n-1).  But shouldn't we count 1 goes to n, or has it already been counted?  Thanks,

Comment: Keep track of what happened to $1$ through all of the switches.  First, we switch it to $2$. From the second position, it's switched to the third. By the end, $1$ has gone all the way to $n$.

Comment: Ahhh that's so cool :-) thanks so much @Omnomnomnom.  Have a great night :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your permutation, in cycles notation, is the cycle $(1\,2\,\dots\, n)$ The signature of a cycle of length $\ell$ is $(-1)^{\ell-1}$, whence the answer.